# Immutable POD class with mutable partner

Tags: scala, akka

I have found myself running into error-prone code; the pattern is this:

```
final class StateVars(val x:Int, val y:Int)

final class StateVarsMutable(var x:Int, var y:Int) {
  // req. case classes & >1 element w/ same ordering
  // - can also do similar with shapeless
  // def snapshot():StateVars = StateVars.tupled( 
  //  StateVarsMutable.unapply(this).get )
  def snapshot() = new StateVars(x, y) // generic
}
```

In the above an instance StateVarsMutable might be contained within an Actor, but the actor may occasionally send a snapshot of its state with StateVars.  It looks like [kailuowang's henkan](https://github.com/kailuowang/henkan) could be used.  Without compromising run-time performance, is there a best or common approach to this situation?

Comment: Need some clarification on this. Does the actor receive a snapshot of `StateVars` or `StateVarsMutable`? and is the runtime performance hit from converting between the 2 case classes?

Comment: For this discussion, the actor sends StateVars; internally, it maintains StateVarsMutable -- but both conversions are appropriate, i.e., `.toMutable` and  `.toImmutable` (`.snapshot()` above).   I mention performance as I contemplated possible solutions that introduce strings for field names or those that introduce additional copies e.g., via `tupled` or `HList`.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is solely the  (misguided) desire to use mutable internal state.

Comment: Its common for an Actor to keep state in a mutable variable, but can be avoided. For your scenario, I would create a companion object for the case class(es) with an `apply` method to handle the conversion between the mutable and immutable versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mutability of Immutable Classes**

The pattern described in the question is unnecessary.

The [`case class` in scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) solves the problem that the question is trying to address by using [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) patterns.

Modifying the question's class declaration to include "case":

```
final case class StateVars(x: Int, y: Int)
```

It is now possible to "mutate" this state by returning new objects that represent the new state:

```
val initialState = StateVars(0,0)

//Increment x while keeping y the same
val incrementX : StateVars = initialState copy (x = initialState.x + 1)

//Increment y while keeping x the same
val incrementY : StateVars = initialState copy (y = initialState.y + 1)
```

If you need to continuously maintain a "snapshot" then use a `var`:

```
var snapshot : StateVars = StateVars(0,0)

snapshot = snapshot copy (x = snapshot.x + 1, y = snapshot.y +1)
```

**Within Actors**

It is possible to write an `Actor` that maintains a "snapshot" using the `become` functionality to allow for changing values:

```
object StateVarsRequest

class StateVarsActor(initialStateVars : StateVars) extends Actor {

  private def update(currentSnapshot: StateVars) : Receive = {
    case stateVars : StateVars => context become update(stateVars)
    case _ : StateVarsRequest  => sender ! currentSnapshot
  }

  override def receive : Receive = update(initialStateVars)
}
```

The `snapshot` can be thought of as a pointer to an immutable class.  When a requester receives the snapshot in a message they are not getting the mutable pointer, but rather the immutable data.

So if the snapshot changes after a requester has received their data then the requester's data does not change.